In Hand & Foot, how many points is needed to make an open?
The first player on a team to initially play (open) must play a minimum number of points to open.  I know that in Canasta, in order to open the levels are:

50 points for scores up to 1495
90 points for score up to 2995
120 for scores 3000 and up.


Hand and Foot is related to Canasta, but has enough rules changes to be its own game!
Instead of playing to a point goal, you typically play four rounds.  The points needed for your initial meld increase as the rounds are played.

Round 1: 50 points to open.
Round 2: 90 points to open.
Round 3: 120 points to open.
Round 4: 150 points to open.

